# Processing the Paypal Reply

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am currently facing issues with checking the status when paypal replies to page (paypal.aspx) . I am entering text if the the status is "VERIFIED".

```
    if (strResponse == "VERIFIED")
        {

           StreamWriter swr = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("Textfile.txt"));
           swr.WriteLine("----verified(" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ")--");
           swr.Dispose();
        }
```

When i check my text file there is nothing . what can be wrong?

Comment: you confuse the paypal code with the error on writing file. I suggest you to focus only on the error of stremwriter.

Comment: Can you tell me what error can be there in streamwriter??

Comment: I do not know the error, warp it with try/catch to see what the error is. Maybe you need to add flags like the write and append.

Comment: I did everyting, i also tried the insert statement. But I guess their is no response from paypal side to this page.

Comment: The wrong here is that you do not actual save to the file what you get. Make a simple function and try to see if you can write anything on this file first.

Answer (score 0):

Do you even know if Paypal is sending the request to your page? Try checking your IIS logs and make sure the file is being hit.

Also I think you are missing the

```
swr.Close()
```

method